# Any situation where I can't help using 'continue' within a switch statement?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I just wonder why so many people end up using `continue` inside switch statements when actually they don't need it at all, for example, a nested switch statement within a loop. Let's say somebody wrote this C code

```
int get_option(){...}

main(){
    int option;

    while(1){
      option = get_option();
      switch(option){
      case 0: 
          /* do something */
          continue;  
      case 1:
          /* do something */
          break;
      case 2:
          /* do something */
          continue;  
      default:
}
```

Here, ending a case with `continue` seems to make exactly the same result as `break`. In my opinion, the formal way to end a switch statement is by using `break` because you can always use it to end a case whether the statement is nested within a loop or not anyway. Using `continue` here seems terrible to me.

If you can think of any situation where I really need `continue` inside a switch statement, please give me an idea.

Comment: This question is a little broad, but what if there was something *after* the switch statement that you didn't want executed for some cases? This would mean `continue` is the correct path, because `break` would cause the part after the switch to execute too.

Comment: If the switch statement isn't the last thing in the loop it would make a difference because continue jumps back to the top of the loop.

Comment: `continue` has nothing to do with `switch` statements. It acts on loops!

Comment: I don't quite see why you think `continue`would be mis-placed or *looks terrible* to you. After all, that's exactly the case it is intended for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used to to decide whether some statements **after** the switch statement should be executed. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int get_option(void)
{
    int num;
    do{
        num = getchar();
    } while(isspace(num));
    if(isdigit(num))
        return num - '0';
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int option;
    while(1){
        option = get_option();
        switch(option){
            case 0: 
                puts("You've entered 0");
                continue; // <--- continue; gives you nothing
            case 1:
                puts("You've entered 1");
                break; // <--- break; gives you "You've entered an odd number"
            case 2:
                puts("You've entered 2");
                continue;
            default:
                puts("Input out of range!");
                continue;
        }
        puts("You've entered an odd number"); // <--- Notice this line
    }
}
```

Input and output:

```
0
You've entered 0
1
You've entered 1
You've entered an odd number
2
You've entered 2
3
Input out of range!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int get_option(){...}

main(){
  int option;
  while(1){
    option = get_option();
    switch(option){
      case 0: 
        /* do something */
        continue;
      case 1:
        /* do something */
        break;
      case 2:
        /* do something */
        continue;  
      default:
    }
    /* this is executed if (option!=0)&&(option!=2)
       otherwise skipped */
  }
}
```